# How can I access a Field current value inside a table?

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, frontend, formik

I have a table and, inside each of the rows, I have a `Field` component that is part of a `Formik` form.

I want to access the current value of that `Field` when I press a button (that is inside each of the rows as well), and pass that value to another function `onClick`.

This is the code I have right now:

```
          <TableRow
            hover
            key={token.id}
            sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }}
            selected={isItemSelected}
            onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, token.address, 0, 0, "0")}
          >
            <TableCell padding="checkbox">
              <Checkbox
                color="primary"
                checked={isItemSelected}
                inputProps={{
                  'aria-labelledby': labelId,
                }}
              />
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">{token.name}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">{token.symbol}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">{token.address}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">{token.maxAmount}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">
              <Formik
                initialValues={{
                  tokenAmount: 0,
                }}
              >
                <Form>
                  <Field id="tokenAmount" name="tokenAmount" type="number" disabled={false} />
                </Form>
              </Formik>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">
              <Button disabled={!isItemSelected} onClick={() => approveERC20Token(token.address, props.smartVaultContract, tokenAmount.value)} color="primary" variant="contained" >
                Approve
              </Button>
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
      )})}
```

I want to get the value of the `Field` as the third argument of the function `approveERC20Token` (currently identified as `tokenAmount.value`).

How should I configure `Formik` to achieve this behaviour and how do I identify each of the different fields based on the index of the table?

Comment: you can move the Formik form to wrap the entire table instead of individual table cells. This way you can use the Formik values object to access the current value of each Field when the button is clicked https://formik.org/docs/tutorial here is an example`initialValues`

Comment: Can you explain how can I access the Formik values object? I don't know how to declare the `useFormik()` hook in this context as I am getting `React Hook "useFormik" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function` if I declare inside the table.

Comment: There are many ways to do that let me show you an example I have used formik many times!